# Precise widh for bootstrap blocks

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Need your help.

Is there a way to set a precise width for blocks(columns) in bootstrap 3?
For example: I need one column say col-md-3 - whose width should be 22%. I mean, how to achieve more precision?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In each break point there is a set of column classes. The col-md columns are in the default min-width: 992 media queries. The columns have to add up to 12 to format across the width of the .container. You can change the widths of a particular column, but the columns next to it also have to be adjusted to make 100%. Also, when you change the width, you can't use the push pulls and offsets without them being messed up. All things work together. I would just make my own css and not use the bootstrap classes.

```
 @media (min-width:992px) {

      .my-row .col-md-3 {width:22%}
      .my-row .col-md-4 {width:39%}

    }
```

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/husebu/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

Change you css code to

(I guess col-md-3 is a class)

```
.col-md-3{
    width:22%;
    display:block;
}
```

Check this fiddle for [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Callie_/UJEB8/)